# python code to download files from links in table in the website

Tags: python

I need to write a python code to download files from links in a table in the website. I know how to pull it from a single link, but I don't know how to pull it from the table. Below is the screenshot of the link.

[image: Screenshot of the website table]

I need to learn how to download files from multiple links organized in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). They'll provide you with all the tools you need to 1) download a webpage (requests) 2) parse the returned HTML and locate the link within the table (beautiful soup) then 4) download the file (requests).